# Error in R when using psych- Error in if (n.obs < n.obs.original) message("Warning, missing data were found for ", : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, icc, psych, irr

Whenever I try to analyse my data using R it comes up with the above error message does anybody know why this is?

Comment: Hi Amelia! Welcome to SO. Could you please offer additional information about the error? Please include information about your `sessionInfo()` and a piece of code or deeper description of how and when the error occurs. You can check this post to have some inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.